# Pandas DF Conditional filtering

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I would like to select all rows for each group after the last time a condition is met for that group.

The condition is all rows (per group) after the first 1 in the Name column.

THis is the Pandas df

[image]

Expected Result

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear, do you want to select after the **first** or **last** `1`?

Comment: In addition, what should happen if you have only 0s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.groupby` + `.idxmax()`:

```py
out = df.groupby("Group", group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.loc[g["Name"].idxmax() :])
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  Group  Name  Value
1     A     1    200
2     A     0    300
4     B     1    500
5     B     0    600
```

---

Initial `df`:

```
  Group  Name  Value
0     A     0    100
1     A     1    200
2     A     0    300
3     B     0    400
4     B     1    500
5     B     0    600
```

Comment: The Name columns will not have 0 and 1 it will have a string. In that case what can we do ?

Comment: @EashwarGV You can use `g.loc[(g["Name"] == "some name").idxmax() :]`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous as your 1s are both the first and last of each group. I used a different example for clarity (new group D).

If you want to select after the **first** `1`, use a [`groupby.cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df[df['Name'].eq(1).groupby(df['Group']).cummax()]
```

Output:

```
   Group  Name  value
2      A     1  15000
3      A     0   2000
5      B     1   4000
6      B     0   1550
7      B     0   2500
8      B     0   3200
10     C     1   2500
11     C     0   3000
12     C     0   4500
13     C     0   5000
15     D     1      2  # first 1
16     D     0      3
17     D     1      4  # last 1
18     D     0      5
```

Intermediates:

```
   Group  Name  value  eq(1)  cummax
0      A     0   1000  False   False
1      A     0   2000  False   False
2      A     1  15000   True    True
3      A     0   2000  False    True
4      B     0   1000  False   False
5      B     1   4000   True    True
6      B     0   1550  False    True
7      B     0   2500  False    True
8      B     0   3200  False    True
9      C     0   1250  False   False
10     C     1   2500   True    True
11     C     0   3000  False    True
12     C     0   4500  False    True
13     C     0   5000  False    True
14     D     0      1  False   False
15     D     1      2   True    True
16     D     0      3  False    True
17     D     1      4   True    True
18     D     0      5  False    True
```

If you want to select after the **last** `1` use a similar logic but with a custom [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) combining [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummin.html) on the reversed Series:

```
out = df[df.loc[::-1, 'Name'].ne(1).groupby(df['Group'])
           .transform(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=True).cummin())[::-1]
        ]
```

Output:

```
   Group  Name  value
2      A     1  15000
3      A     0   2000
5      B     1   4000
6      B     0   1550
7      B     0   2500
8      B     0   3200
10     C     1   2500
11     C     0   3000
12     C     0   4500
13     C     0   5000
17     D     1      4  # last 1
18     D     0      5
```

Used input:

```
   Group  Name  value
0      A     0   1000
1      A     0   2000
2      A     1  15000
3      A     0   2000
4      B     0   1000
5      B     1   4000
6      B     0   1550
7      B     0   2500
8      B     0   3200
9      C     0   1250
10     C     1   2500
11     C     0   3000
12     C     0   4500
13     C     0   5000
14     D     0      1
15     D     1      2
16     D     0      3
17     D     1      4
18     D     0      5
```